# jstl for each loop inside access another jstl variable with index

Tags: jstl

In JSTL how to access another var with index inside this loop

```
 <c:set var="cmbIndex" value="${TXTTITLE}"> </c:set>  this variable have 1,6,3....
<c:forEach var="item" items="${HDNNAMEANDID}" varStatus="row">
    <option value='<c:out value="${cmbIndex[row.index]}"/>'>${item}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

it gives error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access it without the c:out. Also what type of collection is TXTTITLE? if an array it should work as:

```
<c:set var="cmbIndex" value="${TXTTITLE}"> </c:set>  
<c:forEach var="item" items="${HDNNAMEANDID}" varStatus="row">
    <option value='${cmbIndex[row.index]}'> ${item}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

If a list type collection:

```
<c:set var="cmbIndex" value="${TXTTITLE}"> </c:set>  
<c:forEach var="item" items="${HDNNAMEANDID}" varStatus="row">
    <option value='${cmbIndex.get(row.index)}'> ${item}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

You could also just access directly:

```
    <option value='${TXTTITLE[row.index]}'> ${item}</option>
    // OR
    <option value='${TXTTITLE.get(row.index)}'> ${item}</option>
```

---

Given that TXTTITLE is a comma separated value, if you are trying to access this by position of the number in the comma separated list, I would use split() and convert it to a String array:

```
<c:set var="cmbIndex" value="${TXTTITLE.split(',')}"> </c:set>  
...
<option value='${cmbIndex[row.index]}'> ${item}</option>
```